# jQuery - select subset of elements within a saved set of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

From this:

```
var $saved = $('#parent').find('a');
```

How can I now subselect those elements in `$saved` which have class `myClass`?

I don't want descendents (so `find` or `children` are no good), I want the subset of $saved.

```
var $refined = $saved.[something something];
```

Essentially, I want `$refined` to be equal to `$('#parent').find('a.myClass');` but to start from `$saved`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use filter method:

```
var $refined = $saved.filter(".myClass");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter` method.

```
var $refined = $saved.filter('.myClass');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through saved collection to find out the elements with class myClass.

```
var $refined  = $saved.each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('class') == 'myClass')
      return $(this);
});
```

Or you can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) jquery function to apply selector.

```
 var $refined  = $saved.filter('myClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

may be this one can help

```
var $refined = $saved.filter('.myClass');
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 1):

```
$saved.each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('test')) alert($(this).text());
        });
```